# IE9 Automation of Button Click

Tags: automation, internet-explorer-9, ui-automation

Several of my vendor's require me to place orders thru their websites.  I have automated the process by clicking on a button in my order processing program.  My program will open the default browser (now IE 9 after my  previous computer died), navigate to the vendor's website order page, fill out the information fields, and then click the form submit button.

```
 this.oIE.Document.all.ctl00_MainContent_Login1_LoginButton.click()
```

or 
     this.oIE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_Login1_LoginButton").click()

The problem appears to occur only when the button has an "onclick" value.

In IE8, the click() event executes the onclick code.  In IE9, the click event returns a generic object.  It does not fire the onclick code.

I have tried x.FireEvent("click"), but this returns an object as well.  It appears that IE9 DOM onclick values cannot be executed by external programs.

My program works fine on IE8  (I use Chrome, IE, FireFox with different settings and logins, so changing the default browser is not really an option.  Also, some of my vendors demand that I use IE as their sites are broken on the other browsers.)

Any advice on a permanent fix for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I could have written your question verbatim, and have been fighting this for as long as you have.

Stupid, stupid problem: The `click()` function now requires a parameter:  `click(1)`

```
w = this.oIE.Document
z = w.getElementById("btn-header-input-signin")
z.click(1)
```

Haven't thoroughly tested this, but it works on the US Postal Service login page.

Answer (score 0):

The function that the button click calls will presumably have the same name on each browser.  Can you call that function instead?

Simulating the button click seems an unnecessary step.  Also, have you tried jQuery?  Libraries like that try to smooth away browser differences.

Comment: JQuery is great if you are developing the HTML to show in a browser.  But, my program is automating the human sitting at the computer, not the website being shown to the human.  I am filling out a variety of forms on other peoples websites, I do not have access to the HTML other than "View Page Source".     Do you know how to execute the onclick code thru the DOM?

Comment: I ended up setting the IE9 compatibility mode on for the vendors websites with this issue.  Hopefully, I will remember this when they revise their sites and it is broken again.  (As a newbie with this login, stackoverflow will not let me answer my own questions within 8 hours of posing a question.)